При запуске билда в Android Studio, диск, процессор и память грузятся на 100%
У меня ноутбук Acer Extensa 15, на нём сейчас установлено 8гб памяти, но главная проблема, что я не могу разрабатывать мобильные приложения на Kotlin, потому что попросту при запуске билда ноут бьётся по всем фронтам в 100% как это фиксить?
Система Win 11
Android Studio 2024.1.1
К слову я пытаюсь запустить просто базовый проект, который создаётся по-умолчанию.

Это норма! тыц

Нужно более производительные системы брать. Кстати, название ноутбука ни о чем не говорит!Быстрое гугление показало, что на борту проц с 1.2ГГц частотой, даже если там будет 4 ядра - этого очень мало!

Вообще, у меня процессор AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.10 GHz
ОП 8гб, есть ли смысл расширять ОП или лучше ноут другой подбирать?

Я лично пересел на 32 gb оперативки с 12 ядрами. Раньше сидел на 16gb с 8 ядрами - подтормаживало...
